# Display ISO 8601 date string as local date and time based on navigator.language

Tags: javascript, datetime, localization, locale, iso8601

I've been trying to display the local date and time after parsing ISO string to local timestamp based on navigator.language.

```
let sampleDate = new Date('2018-11-29T09:54:46.863207Z').toLocaleString(navigator.language);
```

So when I change the browser language preferences it reflects the date format in proper locale, but this doesn't seem to work with time part of the ISO string.

Result with browser locale `en-AU`--
`Data Last Updated at 29/11/2018, 3:24:46 pm`

Result with browser locale `en-US` -- `Data Last Updated at 11/29/2018, 3:24:46 pm`

See how only the date format changes based on the locale.It doesn't seem to affect the time component of the ISO 8601 string.

I've tried using moment.js to get the display the date and time in browser locale format but didn't find much success.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What format would you have expected for the time…?

Comment: Oh, you want it to be in Australian/US *timezone*?! Well, that's not what `toLocaleString` does. The locale just defines the *language/format*, not the *timezone*.

Comment: @decee hh:mm:ss. I did not know that. Thanks. 
What about `toLocaeTimeString()`?

Do you know if momenjs does this sort of thing where I just pass 
`moment.locale(navigator.language)` and do `moment().format();`

Comment: Language/locale and timezone are always separate. As a simple example, the US has way more than one timezone, but all use the same locale. You can't deduce one from the other.

Comment: The confusion between language and locale is likely from the nonsensical naming of the first parameter to *toLocaleString* being called "locale". It isn't, it's a language code and should have been called "language".

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to take a UTC date string, convert it to the client browser's local date and time, and format the date based on locale. You may be overthinking it a bit as JavaScript does most of this for you as long as you correctly create the `Date` object.

It is not recommended to parse date strings with the `new Date()` constructor, so the code example below uses a little regex and unpacking to parse the date string, then you can create the date in UTC with `new Date(Date.UTC(...))`. At that point, JavaScript will represent the date object in the client browser's local date and time automatically, then you can use `toLocaleString()` to apply formatting for the client browser's locale. For example:

```js
const s = '2018-11-29T09:54:46.863207Z';
const [y, m, d, hh, mm, ss, ms] = s.match(/\d+/g);
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(y, m - 1, d, hh, mm, ss, ms));
const formatted = date.toLocaleString();
console.log(formatted);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the Date for a particular time zone:

`date.toLocaleDateString('en-AU', {timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney'})`
`date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'})`

You can try this

```
console.log(
  (new Date).toLocaleString('en-AU', {timeZone: 'Australia/Sydney'}) + "\n" + 
  (new Date).toLocaleString('en-US', {timeZone: 'America/New_York'})
)

18/10/2021, 10:05:25 pm
10/18/2021, 7:05:25 AM
```